# React updating prop and rendering based on boolean value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a parent function component which has a boolean (which is set via child component and also used to render some container on parent component).

Is the below setup fine in terms of updating and dynamic rendering based on isSomeBoolean?

```
const [isSomeBoolean, setisSomeBoolean] = useState(true);    
const updateIsSomeBoolean = (boolVal) => {
    setisSomeBoolean(boolVal);
}


<ChildComp updateIsSomeBoolean={updateIsSomeBoolean} /> 
  
{isSomeBoolean && (
    <div className="container">
    ....
    </div>
)
}
```

In the child component, somewhere I invoke the parent function as below;

```
props.updateIsSomeBoolean(false);
```

Comment: Does it work correctly?

Comment: Yes, it seems to....but just wanted to check if it is good in terms of practice and also if it would work for every scenario

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Passing state and controller function to the child component is very normal in react.

But always keep in mind that changing state in parent component will render both components so keep the state near to component where is it required.

In your scenario, you're going in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks....So this line isSomeBoolean && (<div>) would only render the div if "isSomeBoolean" is explicitly true...Would that be correct ?